# Does Changing Content Dynamically With Javascript Affect SEO for Google?

Tags: javascript, ajax, search, responsive-design, seo

I have a website where I have 3 divs in it.

```
<div id="desktop">
<div id="tablet">
<div id="mobile">
```

I use javascript to determine the browser size and then serve up through AJAX the appropriate HTML to fit into the corresponding div.  As the browser size changes it will load as necessary into the other DIVS, and I use media queries to hide or show those divs based on my desired screen sizes for the HTML I'll serve.

If you were to view my source code when the page loads all you would see is just that, those empty divs, but in realty they fill up with content.

Is google smart about seeing the new content that will be in there? Does this give me any kind of SEO penalty?

I did some research and found this article (https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/javascript)

Does my situation apply to Javascript Adaptive?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084003/will-content-loaded-by-ajax-affect-seo-search-engines

Comment: I would argue that that is not a duplicate because of the method by which I'm doing it.  I suppose I'm asking for my particular scenario.